# Regex for getting parentheses within parentheses infinitely

Tags: java, regex

So I have a String of text lets say `"hello world () (foo bar) (foo bar 2 (this looks cozy)) (foo bar 3..."`
Is there a regex pattern I could use that will get the parentheses and include any parentheses inside them to nth depth.
So the matches would be `"()"`, `"(foo bar)"`, `"(foo bar 2 (this looks cozy))"`, `...`?

Comment: In Java regex engine doesn't support recursion so regex may not be best tool here.

Comment: @Pshemo well is there way to do something similar?

Comment: I'd use a loop over the string, not regex

Comment: Thats a classical example for a language that is **not regular** and thus cannot be parsed by regular expressions (see pumping-lemma). Its context-free.

Comment: Summary of comments: you need a DPDA, i.e. a parser with an explicit or implicit stack, not a regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex flavor in Java doesn't support [recursion](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html) like some other flavors do. Instead you can write your own method which will build strings from characters only if they are:

- `(`
- `)`
- inside parenthesis.

To know if currently handled character is inside parenthesis we can create counter which will check parenthesis balance (you can also think of it as counter for *nesting* level). In short: if we saw more `(` than `)` then we are inside unclosed (open) parenthesis section, so we should add current character to resulting string.

Using that idea our code can look like:

```
String str = "hello world () (foo bar) (foo bar 2 (this looks cozy)) (foo bar 3...)";
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

int parenthesisNestingLevel = 0;
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
    if (ch == '(') {
        parenthesisNestingLevel++;
        sb.append(ch);
    } else if (ch == ')') {
        parenthesisNestingLevel--;
        sb.append(ch);
        if (parenthesisNestingLevel == 0) {
            result.add(sb.toString());
            sb.delete(0, sb.length());//reset sb
        }
    } else if (parenthesisNestingLevel > 0) {//we are inside unclosed parenthesis
        sb.append(ch);
    }
}

result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
()
(foo bar)
(foo bar 2 (this looks cozy))
(foo bar 3...)
```

Comment: No 'yet' about it. Regular expressions can't support recursion by definition. Chomsky hierarchy 1956.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Thank you for information. Will need to study it since I am not rally familiar with regex history an theories behind it. But now what confuses me (and is main reason why I added "yet") is existence of `(?R)` in some regex flavors. Based on example https://regex101.com/r/NLElp8/1 from https://stackoverflow.com/a/35271017 it looks like it represents recursion. So are those flavors no longer proper regex?

Comment: That is correct. They are no longer proper regular expressions, by definition.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Thank you for clarification.